# Can we generate *.class files using annotations

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I am just wondering, can we generate .class files using annotation processor without having them in source file.?

For example.

In [Lombak](http://projectlombok.org), we are just setting @Getter, @Setter for fields. But how does the method gets injected in the class files without getting modification in the source file.

Can you provide a sample like how did they do it?

I could get examples, how to create new files using annotations. But, without adding any thing in the source file, how should i let compiler know and that there is a getter method available in the java file.

Answer (score 1):

What Lombok does is a bit hacky and much more complicated than [annotation processing](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/). An annotation processor simply gets called with the members of the syntax tree and generates a new file (typically a Java source file).

Modifying an existing class the way Lombok does is pretty hard. It works by [transforming the AST](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-lombok) and that's something outside of the scope of the normal APT.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write out `.class` files yourself, but the way that these annotations usually work is that the annotation processor generates source files that are then compiled. The compiler keeps looping until no more source files have been generated on a pass and then finishes.

For enhancing an existing class, creating AspectJ inter-type declarations is the usual approach.